# Validate Text Field Length In Between 2 Numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate whether a HTML field is between 11 and 13 characters long.

I have tried using:

```
if(!phoneCheck.test(phone) || (phone.length !>= 11 && phone.length !<=13))
```

But this does not seem to work. It just stops all Javascript as if there is an error in it.

How would i go about doing this?

EDIT:

Sorry i shouldve added a further part of the code:

```
if(!phoneCheck.test(phone) || (phone.length !>= 11 && phone.length !<=13))
{
error = "Please give a valid phone number.";
}
```

The exclamation mark was added so that if it WAS NOT between those lengths then it would trigger the error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The symbols `!>=` and `!<=` don't exist.
The condition code to check if field is between 11 and 13 characters long is:

```
(phone.length >= 11 && phone.length <= 13)
```

OBS:
`<=` means "less or equal" and `>=` means "bigger or equal".
`!` is the logical denial. 
For example: 
`!true` is `false`
and
 `!(a>b)` is true when `a<=b`

EDIT:
With your edit, what you want is to deny the entire sentence, so the solution is:

```
!(phone.length >= 11 && phone.length <= 13)
```

So your if statement should be:

```
if(!phoneCheck.test(phone) || !(phone.length >= 11 && phone.length <=13))
```

Comment: Ahh, thats where i got confused. Where to place the exclamation mark. Cheers bud :)